# How do I remove or uninstall DirectDownloader from Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: software-center, uninstall

I wanted to download a gallery of .jpg file from the Internet. The website suggested the
DirectDownloader program to be installed to be able to download this gallery.

I could install the DirectDownloader (DD) but it seems to be a kind of a bug. There is no use  for this program, only big  problems arises because it cannot run on Ubuntu. Also the Software Center does not work anymore, a blank window comes up whenever I try to launch it.

How can I

- Get rid of DirectDownloader?
- Activate Software Center again?

Please help.

Comment: It would help, if you posted a link to the site where you downloaded DirectDownloader from. Was it a debian package or some other format? Did it require root privileges to install?

Comment: Dear Soulsource !

Comment: Thank you very much it is kind of you wasting your time !

Comment: I restarted my laptop and Software center worked again but the Directdownlouder was still here !

Comment: I restarted my laptop and Software center worked again but the Directdownlouder was still here! The site : [Directdownlouder]www.directdownloader.com  and the current version v.3.032  and sometimes comes a message in a popup : the Directdownloader encountered a serious problem ..the  program must close ! what shell I do after that ? I have no idea !

Comment: Something else: There is a neat command line tool that should be suitable to download thumbnail galleries. It's called wget and is installed per default. You can check out its usage by typing

    man wget

at a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Since I only find a Windows version on that site, I assume you used wine to install it. You can try to use the wine uninstaller, by running (in a terminal emulator or in the run-dialogue - ALT+F2)

```
wine uninstaller
```

That should bring up a dialogue similar to the one used uninstall software in older versions of Windows. You should be able to uninstall the program that way. This will probably not remove the icons from the menus though, nevertheless they should stop working after uninstalling direcdownloader. For me, to remove the icons, it was enough to try to start direct downloader after uninstalling it. If that doesn't work for you, you can remove them manually. You can either use a program named alacarte (in the menus it's listed as Gnome-Main-Menu or something like that, if it's not installed, you can find it in software center by searching for alacarte.), or navigate to the hidden folder .local/share/applications in your home-directory and look for files named wine-Programs-DirectDownloader-DirectDownloader.desktop or similar and check the wine subdirectory.

If this however does not work for you and you are certain that you used wine to install directdownloader, you can try to delete *all* installed windows programs by deleting the hidden .wine-folder in you home directory. As said, this will remove *all* windows programs, so I'd only consider it a **last resort**, as long as any other windows-software additional to directdownloader is installed. Also, this will not remove the icons from the menus, you'll have to delete them manually (see above).

I must confess that I only tried this partially, for I'm not using the default desktop and therefore don't know how exactly it affects Ubuntu. If it also puts itself in autostart, the default directory for this would be the hidden .config/autostart-folder in your home directory.

Comment: Dear Soulsource ! Many thanks for your help !It was very usefull that you advised me !

Comment: I found wine uninstall and as I opened this program I found in its list the Directdoanloader program but to uninstall this program I could not achieve that . The Directdownloader  sent  a popup that a serious problem came and stayed on my laptop .But there is a good thing : In the list of wine uninstaller I found an older program named :Expressdownloader which I wanted to erase as well . And I was able to uninstall this program totally !!  :))) I could uninstall Directdownloader succsessfully  navigating in the hidden folder .local/share/applications in my home-directory !But icon still here!

Comment: I found interesting lines  in  .wine   and here in two files  in system.reg  and  in user.reg :

Comment: system.reg :

[Software\\Classes\\Applications\\DirectDownloader.exe] 1348959171
@=""

[Software\\Classes\\Applications\\DirectDownloader.exe\\shell] 1348959171
@="open"

[Software\\Classes\\Applications\\DirectDownloader.exe\\shell\\open\\command] 1348959171
@="C:\\users\\imre\\Local Settings\\Application Data\\DirectDownloader\\directdownloader.exe run \"%1\""

[Software\\Classes\\ATL.Registrar] 1345981777
@="Registrar Class"

Comment: user.reg :

[Software\\Wine\\MenuFiles] 1349168378
"/home/imre/.config/menus/applications-merged/wine-Programs-DirectDownloader-DirectDownloader.menu"="/home/imre/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/imre/Start Menu/Programs/DirectDownloader/DirectDownloader.lnk"
"/home/imre/.config/menus/applications-merged/wine-Programs-DirectDownloader-Uninstall Program.menu"="/home/imre/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/imre/Start Menu/Programs/DirectDownloader/Uninstall Program.lnk"

Comment: and user.reg  continuing as :                                     "/home/imre/.local/share/applications/wine/Programs/DirectDownloader/DirectDownloader.desktop"="/home/imre/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/imre/Start Menu/Programs/DirectDownloader/DirectDownloader.lnk"
"/home/imre/.local/share/applications/wine/Programs/DirectDownloader/Uninstall Program.desktop"="/home/imre/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/imre/Start Menu/Programs/DirectDownloader/Uninstall Program.lnk"

Comment: My question would be  : these lines must be erased and so the icon  for Directdownloader will be deleted forever ?

Comment: I am not really certain whether this will completely remove it, yet I'd try to delete (maybe make backups, so you can copy them back if anything goes terribly wrong) all the files mentioned in the registry entries, starting with the .exe and maybe the whole folder
/home/imre/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/imre/Local Settings/Application Data/DirectDownloader. After removing all the .lnk and .desktop files I hope that you get rid of it.